# Cannot use foreign key as variable(?)

Tags: c#, linq, foreign-keys

I have two tables enGyerek and enSzulo and enGyerek's foreign key is enSzulo_Id.

[image]

```
var er = new enGyerek()
{
    gy_nev = tbGyereknev.Text,
    gy_kor=tbGyerekkor.Text,
    enSzulo.Id=2, //wrong
    enSzulo=2, //wrong
    enSzulo_Id=2 //wrong
};
```

I don't know how to initialize the szulo id as a foreign key. I cannot leave it blank because it cannot be NULL. So my question is how can I use the foreign key correctly if I want to initialize it?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and post both classes?

Comment: What do you mean by edit my question? Unfortunately I cannot express myself better. :/ I just want to use the foreign key.

Comment: Click on [edit] and paste the code for the classes `enGyerek` and `enSzulo`

Comment: I use a model first database.